# Single page login screen for all password protected Wordpress pages

Tags: wordpress

I have a setup of Wordpress blog with a couple of password-protected pages, each of them with special content and a different password.

I would like to have a login form (password-only) on a single public Wordpress page, which redirects to the corresponding password-protected page, according to the submitted password.

Anybody know of a good free plugin for that or any ideas how to fetch Wordpress pages by password?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution:

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_password = '{$_POST['post_password']}'");

if($result) {
    wp_safe_redirect(get_bloginfo('url') . "/?page_id=" . $result[0]->ID);
} else {
    wp_safe_redirect(wp_get_referer());
}
```

Do you think it is reliable enough?

How can this functionality be implemented in such a way, that it preserve itself upon Wordpress update?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi ezb.I have a similar requirement. Could you elaborate how you implemented your solution? does this code go into the functions.php file? and how does the user login? It will be very helpful if you could explain the details. Thanks!